# How to query a pointer in a ParseObject class?

Tags: android, parse-platform, parse-android-sdk

Hi i made ParseObject which contains a field called Usuario which is a pointer to _User(ParseUser class)

[image: My class Conversaciones]

ive been trying to query for this value with no success...

```
private void queryConversaciones(){
    ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Conversaciones");
    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
        @Override
        public void done(List<ParseObject> objects, ParseException e) {
            for (ParseObject obj:objects
                 ) {
                mensaje=obj.getString("Mensaje");
                enviaMensaje= (ParseUser) obj.get("Usuario");

               // mMessageList.add(obj);

            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: If it has solved your issue, it would be helpful if you could accept my answer. If not, let me know and I will try to help further.

Answer (score 1):

Just add `query.include("key");` to retrieve the pointer object.

So your complete query should look like this:

```java
private void queryConversaciones(){
    ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Conversaciones");

    // Include data at pointer
    query.include("Usuario");

    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
        @Override
        public void done(List<ParseObject> objects, ParseException e) {
            for (ParseObject obj:objects
                 ) {
                mensaje=obj.getString("Mensaje");
                enviaMensaje= (ParseUser) obj.get("Usuario");

               // mMessageList.add(obj);

            }
        }
    });
}
```

Now you should be able to access all the data stored in the `_User` object.

I got all this information from the [relational queries section in the Parse Android guide](https://docs.parseplatform.org/android/guide/#relational-queries).